# Convert Timestamp string date to datetime python

Tags: python

My dataframe contains the column 'date' which is in the format of '2020-01-21 10:00:00'.
I want to add an additional column 'day' which will contain the day of the date.
I'm having a problem converting a date to a day because of the timestamp.
When I execute this code: my_data['date'][0], it outputs Timestamp('2020-01-21 10:00:00'), which prevents me from using datetime method of conversion.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "day", this: "2020-01-21" ?

Comment: Please add an example of your code / data and we can help you.

Comment: My bad I was talking about like Monday through Sunday

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does this help you?

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp('2020-01-21 10:00:00')
>>> ts
Timestamp('2020-01-21 10:00:00')
>>> ts.day_name()
'Tuesday'
```

Similar to this, take your date column and then you can do what you want.

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[pd.Timestamp('2020-01-21 10:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('11-02-2002')]})
>>> df
                    a
0 2020-01-21 10:00:00
1 2002-11-02 00:00:00
>>> df['day'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.day_name())
>>> df
                    a       day
0 2020-01-21 10:00:00   Tuesday
1 2002-11-02 00:00:00  Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume I understand you clearly.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'date':  ['2020-01-21 10:00:00', '2020-01-22 10:00:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['day'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['date'].day, axis=1)

df['day_name'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['date'].day_name(), axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
                 date  day   day_name
0 2020-01-21 10:00:00   21    Tuesday
1 2020-01-22 10:00:00   22  Wednesday
```

Comment: Sorry the day indicates Mondays through Sunday

Comment: @musiklover You can use `row['date'].day_name()` in `df.apply()` to get that.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this for your understanding**

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1528797322
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print("Date time object:", date_time)

d = date_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("Output 2:", d)   

d = date_time.strftime("%d %b, %Y")
print("Output 3:", d)

d = date_time.strftime("%d %B, %Y")
print("Output 4:", d)

d = date_time.strftime("%I%p")
print("Output 5:", d)

d = date_time.strftime("%A")
print("Output 6:", d)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Date time object: 2018-06-12 09:55:22
Output 2: 06/12/2018, 09:55:22
Output 3: 12 Jun, 2018
Output 4: 12 June, 2018
Output 5: 09AM
Output 6: Tuesday
```